# Aes seems cannot work with 128bits FeedbackSize on Mono?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

I want to encrypt data and then send it to the server. Here is my code.

```
var aes = Aes.Create();
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
aes.FeedbackSize = 128;
aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
_encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
```

I debugged it in a console app on .net 6, It worked well. But when I migrate it to the xamarin project, it cannot work. `CreateEncryptor` method thrown an Exception, it said FeedbackSize cannot be more than 64 bits. It seems that the implement of aes on mono does not support 128bits FeedbackSize.
What should I do?

Comment: Switch to .NET 6 iOS `net6.0-ios`. `dotnet new ios` to get started.

Comment: Can you show what line of your code is throwing what Exception exactly?

Comment: @Lex Li Thanks for your advice. I know that, but it is preview now. There are still many imperfections.

Comment: @Stefan Wuebbe The last line. Method `CreateEncryptor` throws CryptographicException. And its message is  "CFB with Feedbaack > 64 bits". Besides, here is the source code about this. [AesCryptoServiceProvider.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/AesCryptoServiceProvider.cs)

Comment: Cool. You can also edit your Question, and directly integrate/copy&paste the C# code there. I'm pretty sure improving the readability of your question will help readers to help you. I'm also a C# programmer but my last AES cryptography project was a few years ago

Comment: Did you write the comment in line 68 of AesCryptoServiceProvider.cs: _// I suppose some attributes differs ?!? because this does not look required_  or somebody else, is it related to the issue you described?

Comment: @Stefan Wuebbe Oh, no. I think you misunderstood me. That is the source code of mono, not my project. It is the implement of abstract class `Aes` on mono. On line 63, they check the FeedbackSize property to ensure it is less than 64, but I surely need to set that property 128.

Comment: A misunderstanding in the Comments to your question might be no problem (I think), as long as you (perhaps in cooperation with commenting SO readers like me) can use it to improve the question until it gets a Useful Answer by someone.  IOW, it might help to integrate you replies in the Comments directly into your Question so that maybe today or tomorrow we'll have an Answer :)

Comment: @Stefan Wuebbe Thanks for your reply. I have solved the problem. After I replaced the class `Aes` to the class `Rijndael`, it works.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! You can also write an Answer to your own Question if you think other readers would benefit from reading more details about your issue and your way to solve it